# Backup everything except one record

Tags: mysqldump

I want to backup my database except `t1` table's one record (`where option='siteurl'`).

I'm trying mysqldump's `--where` command.

```
mysqldump -u root --skip-extended-insert --where "option='siteurl'" konsertvdb t1 > sql.sql
```

This will work if I backup only the `t1` table. But I want to backup all tables, except `t1`'s one record (`where option='siteurl'`) .

```
> mysqldump -u root --skip-extended-insert --where "option='siteurl'" konsertvdb > sql.sql
mysqldump: Couldn't execute 'SELECT /*!40001 SQL_NO_CACHE */ * FROM `wp_commentmeta` WHERE option='siteurl'': Unknown column 'option' in 'where clause' (1054)
```

<sup>*</sup>(`wp_commentmeta` is one of my other tables.)

Can you tell me is it possible?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Its too simple if you have gone through the [mysqldump](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/mysqldump.html#option_mysqldump_ignore-table) manual

First run a mysql dump ignore the table you would like to skip

```
mysqldump -p -u root db_name --ignore-table=db_name.tbl_name > sql.sql
```

Then once more for your table

```
mysqldump -p -u root db_name tbl_name --where "id!=2" >> sql.sql
```

As a note, if you are giving something in --where, it applicable for all the tables your are using. It will be useful in case of multi-tenant db.

Comment: Updated the comment also :)